# Magento 2 Admin Page "Specified invalid parent id (WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel)"

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml

version Magento 2 2.2.1. I have just setted up my localhost version for a magento 2 online shop, the other pages are working fine but when i try to acccess `http://localhost/tfgs-m2/admin_XXXX/` i am getting:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel)

Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel)
#0 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))
#1 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callParent('getResult', Array)
#2 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))
#3 E:\tfgs-m2\generated\code\Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getResult', Array, Array)
#4 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\Menu\Config.php(148): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))
#5 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\Menu\Config.php(111): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu()
#6 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\Url.php(361): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu()
#7 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\Url.php(321): Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu()
#8 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php(276): Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl()
#9 E:\tfgs-m2\generated\code\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys()
#10 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php(208): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->_processUrlKeys()
#11 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#13 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php(143): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 E:\tfgs-m2\generated\code\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#17 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 E:\tfgs-m2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 E:\tfgs-m2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#24 E:\tfgs-m2\index.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap-

>run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)

)
#25 {main}
```

Comment: check 'WeltPixel_Backend' modules, the configuration for menu. Like this `parent="Magento_Sales::sales"` in  `WeltPixel_Backend` module in `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

Comment: can you be more specific, how do i do that?

Comment: @CompuScie Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install below extension and try again. I think it requires weltpixel backend extension and it may not be present in your setup.

https://github.com/sonpn/m2-weltpixel-backend

Or try to find WeltPixel\Backend extension in your downloaded package and install from there.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to the conversation. I had a similar error after upgrading to Magento 2.3.3:

`Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Review::report_review)`

It occurred because the Magento_Review-module was disabled in `app/etc/config.php`. Enabling the module resolved the error and allowed me to login to my backend.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder named "WeltPixel/Backend" and add that folder WeltPixel. 
It's Done.